# GraphRbacManagementClient.applications.create() returns Access Token missing or malformed

Tags: python, azure

We're trying to create an Azure application registration using the Python SDK (v2.0) and the current user's CLI credentials.

```
from azure.common.credentials import get_azure_cli_credentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

credentials, subscription_id = get_azure_cli_credentials()
client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials, 'my-tenant-id')
app_parameters = {
    'available_to_other_tenants': False,
    'display_name': 'my-app-name',
    'identifier_uris': ['http://my-app-name.com']
}
app = client.applications.create(app_parameters)
```

But this returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/my-app-code/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/graphrbac/operations/applications_operations.py", line 86, in create
    raise models.GraphErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Access Token missing or malformed.
```

We noted that we can avoid this error when using `ServicePrincipalCredentials` by including `resource='https://graph.windows.net'` in the constructor, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent way to do this when using `get_azure_cli_credentials()`.

Are we doing something wrong, or should this work?

Please do not reply that we should be using `ServicePrincipalCredentials`.  Our use case is explicitly that the interactive user can create/register an Azure application using the Python SDK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_azure_cli_credentials` is indeed not able yet to provide you a Credentials class with a "resource" definition different than ARM for now (now being: azure-common 1.1.10 and below)

You can workaround by doing:

```
from azure.common.credentials import get_cli_profile
profile = get_cli_profile()
cred, subscription_id, _ = profile.get_login_credentials(resource='https://graph.windows.net')
```

Please create an issue on https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python, with a link to this SO, and I will try to do it for the next release of azure-common.

(I work at MS and own this code)

**Edit:** Released part of 1.1.11
https://pypi.org/project/azure-common/1.1.11/

```
from azure.common.credentials import get_azure_cli_credentials
cred, subscription_id = get_azure_cli_credentials(resource='https://graph.windows.net')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the credentials and tenant_id at once and create an client line this:

```
from azure.common.credentials import get_azure_cli_credentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

cred, _, tenant_id = get_azure_cli_credentials(
    resource='https://graph.windows.net',
    with_tenant=True)
client = GraphRbacManagementClient(cred, tenant_id)
```

This works like a charm.

Note that this api is deprecated. Favour the new Microsoft Graph (over Azure AD Graph).